# How does glog LOG(INFO) << "something" work?

Tags: c++, glog

I was trying to source debug (only have windows) glog code. One part which i am unable to unearth was how does

```
LOG(INFO) << "something"
```

move the string into the buffer?

From what i could make out it is,

```
LogMessageData::message_text_
```

which needs to be populated with the log message. But i could not find out how the message gets pushed into it.

Comment: You could look for the `LOG` and `INFO` symbols and see how they are defined and what they do. And use a debugger to step into the `LOG` "call" to see what it does as well.

Comment: At a guess it creates an object with an overloaded stream operator that streams the log message into whatever log destination you have configured

Comment: Look for `COMPACT_GOOGLE_LOG_INFO` (or other severity), it is basically alias for `google::LogMessage` or similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically `LOG(INFO)` is returning you a reference to `std::ostream`; to which you are writing your string. Quick look at the glog code shows how it is implemented.

In `src/windows/glog/logging.h` - you would see `LOG()` is a Macro, acccepting severity as a parameter. This one just appends `INFO` to `COMPACT_GOOGLE_LOG_` and calls `stream()` of it...

```
#define LOG(severity) COMPACT_GOOGLE_LOG_ ## severity.stream()
```

the same file has definition of `COMPACT_GOOGLE_LOG_INFO` and it shows this is nothing but a function call - 
 `google::LogMessage().stream();`

```
398 #if GOOGLE_STRIP_LOG == 0
399 #define COMPACT_GOOGLE_LOG_INFO google::LogMessage( \                                                                                                                                                            400       __FILE__, __LINE__)
401 #define LOG_TO_STRING_INFO(message) google::LogMessage( \
402       __FILE__, __LINE__, google::GLOG_INFO, message)
403 #else
404 #define COMPACT_GOOGLE_LOG_INFO google::NullStream()
405 #define LOG_TO_STRING_INFO(message) google::NullStream()
406 #endif
```

Now, look at the `src/logging.cc` file for LogMessage's stream function..
This is returning you a reference to ostream to which you are redirecting your string using `<<`

`LOG(INFO)<<"something";`

```
1476 ostream& LogMessage::stream() {                                                                                                                                                                                                     
1477   return data_->stream_;
1478 }
```

here `data_->stream_` is an object of `LogStream` which is derived from `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 3):

If you look in to the LOG(INFO) macro, it will expand to a c++ code like std::cout on pre-processing stage (before the compilation of code). You will have to set a compiler flag to generate macro expanded file to see substituted codes lines. (This is depend on the compiler you are using. Just search on the internet)

So,

```
LOG(INFO) << "something"
```

becomes some code like

```
std::cout << "something"
```

Note that in above example std::cout is used to elaborate what is going under the hood.In you source code there might be different code instead of std::cout

Rest is up to the overloading of operator <<.  Which used as insertion operator in loggers and output streams. Internally this operator is overloaded insert given data to logger or any other output stream etc;